# Rain fall a full day in big matches

Tags: rules, cricket, interruption

What will happen if the rain stops play for the whole day in big matches such as finals played for World Cup or Asia cup or currently being played Champions Trophy.

Does the match will be played again if the rain does not stop? as the match which was supposed to be played was having a big value.

Also what will be action if the match stopped for whole day after the toss was won by a team ?

What will be considerations for such rain affected matches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If rain fall a full day on final matches of a big tournament, then the teams will be declared joint winners. This is the rule on current ICC champions trophy.

But, in 2002 ICC Champions Trophy final between India and Srilanka, when the result was not able to find as the minmum number of overs required for DL method was not bowled, the match was rescheduled to the next day. But, the same story continues on next day, then both the teams were announced joint winners.

[Source -wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_Champions_Trophy#2002_ICC_Champions_Trophy)